# Using article "the" with famous places?

Tags: definite-article, proper-nouns

I'm editing a children's book about wonders of the World. In this book, the authors are not native speakers(they are XACT BOOK(India)), and they wrote these specific places without article "the":

> -It is Taj Mahal.
>
> -It is Tower of Pisa.

At first, I thought it's okay, but there are some pages has article "the":

> -It is the Great Pyramid of Giza.
>
> -It is the Temple of Artemis.

These sentences really make me confused. After researching, this website-https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/ - gives me some advice:

> Do use the before:
>
> > names of rivers, oceans, and seas: the Nile, the Pacific
> >
> > points on the globe: the Equator, the North Pole
> >
> > geographical areas: the Middle East, the West
> >     deserts, forests, gulfs, and peninsulas: the Sahara, the Persian Gulf, the Black Forest, the Iberian Peninsula

Unfortunately, I'm still not sure that adding "the" before each wonder's name is a right choice. Should I add article "the" or not? I already posted this problem in [another website](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/using-article-the.3085406/#post-15602378), but I'm still in vain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid, if you are looking for a **rule**, you may not get one especially when it comes to having the article before some monuments/buildings.

Articles are annoying! And, for some topics, you just need to *learn* them as they are practiced. And, that's it! You just touched the topic which should be learned as you read more and more authentic sources.

[BBC explains this:](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv287.shtml)

When it comes to buildings, it is **more difficult** to see a pattern emerging. It is **more a case of Learn It.** Compare the following:

> The Eiffel Tower and the Tower of London are two landmarks in the capital cities of France and Britain.
>
> If you come to London, be sure to visit Buckingham Palace, Westminster Abbey and the Houses of Parliament.
>
> Where's Charing Cross station?~ It's off Trafalgar Square, between the Post Office and Coutts Bank in the Strand.

So, when recently Zuckerberg visited India, [he did visit ***The Taj Mahal***](http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/2015/10/27/mark-zuckerberg-india-visits-taj-mahal/74692660/) *(Ignore the headlines, it does not have the article because of '[headlinese](http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/2015/10/27/mark-zuckerberg-india-visits-taj-mahal/74692660/)')*

And, it is [***The (Leaning) Tower of Pisa***](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/britains-answer-leaning-tower-pisa-6598011).

Comment: "Learn it"? - does it mean "learn by heart"?
p/s: Thanks for your information.

Comment: Articles must be difficult for you indeed, I think. It's a little sad that even with good references and examples, you still got the capitalization of *the* wrong.